# Clarification on the use of subsequences to prove that in a metric space a sequence in a compact subset admits a convergent subsequence in the subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Lemma:** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and let $K \subseteq X$ compact. If $E\subseteq K$ is infinite then $Der(E)\neq \emptyset$ , where $Der(E)$ is the set of accumulation points

**Theorem**

Let (X,d) be a metric space and let $K \subseteq X$ be compact in $(X,\tau_d)$ Let $p_n$ be a sequence in $K$, then there exist a convergent subsequence of $p_n$ to an element of $K$

**proof:**

Let $E=\{p_n| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be the image set of the sequence.

$(\alpha)$ If E is finite, there exists an strictly increasing sequence $n_k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{n_i}=p_{n_j}$, for each $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$. Now the subsequence $p_{n_k}$ is constant and therefore convergent

Let's suppose that $E$ is infinite, now using the lemma, $E$ has an accumulation point $p_0$ and $p_0 \in K$ because K is closed.

$(\beta)$ Then $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $p_{n_k} \neq p_0$ such that $p_{n_k} \in B_d(p_0, \frac{1}{k})$. Now the subsequence $p_{n_k}$ converges to $p_0$

**The use of subsequences confuses me a bit, and I don't see the point:**

**In $(\alpha)$ , why can't just I just say:**

If $E$ is finite, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > n_0$   $p_{n}=p_{0}$ constant, that is the sequence is $\{ P_1, P_2,...P_{n_0}, P_0,P_0, P_0...\}$

**And in $(\beta)$ , why can't just I just say:**

$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $p_{k} \neq p_0$ such that $p_{k} \in B_d(p_0, \frac{1}{k})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(\alpha)$, we can’t say that the sequence is constant from some point on because it needn’t be true: consider the real sequence $\langle(-1)^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, which alternates between $1$ and $-1$.

As for $(\beta)$, your suggestion essentially renames some of the points of the original sequence. Originally $p_2$, say, was the second term of the sequence; if the second term of the sequence was not in $B_d\left(p_0,\frac1k\right)$, your $p_2$ might actually be the original $p_{100}$. This is at best confusing. Your source follows the usual practice: in my example, it would say that $n_2=100$. The point retains its original name, $p_{100}$, but the $n_2$ subscript makes it clear that it’s the second point of the subsequence.

Your source is a bit sloppy, however. In order for $\langle p_{n_k}:k\ge 1\rangle$ to be a subsequence of the original sequence, the indices $n_k$ must be strictly increasing. It should therefore say that there is an $n_1$ such that $p_{n_1}\in B_d(p_0,1)$, and for each $k>1$ there is an $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that $p_{n_k}\in B_d\left(p_0,\frac1k\right)$.

Comment: In $\alpha$ of the source, what allos to state the existence of a strictly increasing sequence $n_k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{n_i}=p_{n_j}$ and what allows to conclude that the subsequence $p_{n_k}$ is constant?

Comment: @mathlover: We’re assuming that $E$ is finite, so there must be some $x\in E$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb N:p_n=x\}$ is infinite. List the members of this set in increasing order: $M=\{n_k:k\ge 1\}$, where $n_k<n_{k+1}$ for each $k\ge 1$. Then $p_{n_k}=x$ for each $k\ge 1$, so $p_{n_i}=p_{n_j}$ for all $i,j\ge 1$.

Comment: " It should therefore say that there is an $n_1$ such that $p_{n_1}\in B_d(p_0,1)$, and for each $k>1$ there is an $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that $p_{n_k}\in B_d\left(p_0,\frac1k\right)$."... what is the point of separating the case$ k=1$ from the case$ k>1$?

Comment: @mathlover: Very simple: there is no $n_0$, so we can’t require that $n_1>n_0$.

Comment: I meant why didn't you said:  " It should therefore say that there is an $n_k$  such that for each $k>0$ $p_{n_k}\in B_d\left(p_0,\frac1k\right)$."...

Comment: isn't it obvious it k is 1,2,3...?

Comment: @mathlover: But as I already pointed out, **that’s not enough**: we need to ensure that $\langle n_k:k\ge 1\rangle$ is a strictly increasing sequence, so that $\langle p_{n_k}:k\ge 1\rangle$ really is a subsequence of $\langle p_n:n\ge 1\rangle$.